# Django not running: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'

Tags: django, python-3.x, ubuntu, apache2, mod-wsgi

I have installed django website in a new Ubuntu 17.10 server. It is based on python3. It works fine when i run the website in development mode using

`python manage.py runserver`

But when i tried to configure it via apache2 webserver in `port 80`  by adding wsgi in apache by editing default config file as shown..

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    <Directory /home/usr/mygpsproject/gps_restapi/gps_restapi>
        <Files wsgi.py>
            Require all granted
        </Files>
    </Directory>

    WSGIDaemonProcess gps_restapi python-path=/home/usr/mygpsproject/gps_restapi/ python-home=/home/usr/mygpsproject/venv/bin/
    WSGIProcessGroup gps_restapi
    WSGIScriptAlias / /home/usr/mygpsproject/gps_restapi/gps_restapi/wsgi.py

</VirtualHost>
```

but Site is not working. When I checked the apache error log to find this error...

```
[Sat Apr 14 16:16:09.201739 2018] [core:notice] [pid 5089:tid 140258267696064] AH00051: child pid 7500 exit signal Aborted (6), possible coredump in /etc/apache2
Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: Unable to get the locale encoding
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'

Current thread 0x00007f906c390bc0 (most recent call first):
```

I am not able to find what is this encodings module. it worked fine in development mode. so python is not missing any libraries for sure.

What could be the problem with my configuration.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of:

```
python-home=/home/usr/mygpsproject/venv/bin/
```

you should be using:

```
python-home=/home/usr/mygpsproject/venv
```

Review the documentation on using virtual environments. You are supposed to point to the root of the virtual environment as given by `sys.prefix`, not the `bin` directory.

- http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/virtual-environments.html

Also ensure that the virtual environment is created from the same Python version that mod_wsgi was compiled for.

Finally, depending on the Linux distribution used, you also shouldn't place your code under your personal home directory as the permissions on the home directory can be such that the user that runs your code as under Apache can't access the home directory.

Comment: Yeah thanks @Graham, When I changed it as you mentioned The error in the apache error log disappeared. and it says

`[Sun Apr 15 09:01:45.143640 2018] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 27444:tid 140062344223680] AH00489: Apache/2.4.27 (Ubuntu) mod_wsgi/4.5.17 Python/3.6 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sun Apr 15 09:01:45.143741 2018] [core:notice] [pid 27444:tid 140062344223680] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
`
Still it is not working. What could be the problem. pls help.

Comment: Then it is a different problem now. Suggest accepting this answer and then create a new issue for next one. You will need to define 'still not working'. You must see an error message in the browser and/or log file. If necessary set ``DEBUG=True`` in Django settings file to see if it shows the error in the browser. Otherwise set up Django to log errors. Either way, create a new question for the next issue.